# Random data generation for hurdle model using R

Tags: r, dataset, simulation, zero-inflation, data-generating-process

I would like to generate random data for a distribution which takes the form of hurdle-like model. Let's denote a random variable *X* with probability mass function
\begin{align}
Pr(X=0)&=\alpha\\
Pr(X=1)&=\beta\\
Pr(X=x)&=(1-\alpha-\beta)f(x;\theta)\quad x\geq2,
\end{align}
where
$\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}{f(x;\theta)}=1, 0<\alpha<1, 0<\beta<1, \theta>0$. How to generate random data, say $N=1000$?

P/s: This is not related to GLM. Just curious to generate data like this using R.

Comment: Just the usual: generate a uniform $U$ and compare with the cdf.

Comment: Thanks, the cdf is not in closed form. So, I have to figure out another way to do it. Thank you by the way for your comment.

Comment: The cdf is in closed form:$$F(x)=\sum_{i=0}^x Pr(X=i)$$

Comment: I understand that but when $x\geq2$, the $f(x;\theta)$ is not in the closed form.

Comment: In that case the question is too vague since you do not provide any information about $f(x;\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible R implementation of FPO's answer, using an example distribution and parameter values:

```
set.seed(921078628)
f <- function(x, theta) dpois(x - 2L, theta) # example f(x;theta)
alpha <- 0.1; beta <- 0.04; theta <- 3.5 # example values

pdf <- c(alpha, beta)
currsum <- sum(pdf)
const <- 1 - currsum
i <- 2L
while(currsum < 1) {
  if (i == length(pdf)) length(pdf) <- i*2L
  pdf[i <- i + 1L] <- const*f(i, theta)
  currsum <- currsum + pdf[i]
}
pdf <- pdf[1:i]
sample(0:(length(pdf) - 1), 100, TRUE, prob = pdf)
#>   [1]  3  5  9  4  6  9  9  3  6  8  4  4  5  3  8  8  9  6  5  5  6  5  4  1  4
#>  [26]  5  6  6  5  3  4  3  4  5  4  5  5  6  5  3  9  0  7  9  0  6  7  5  3  6
#>  [51]  6 10  5  5  6  7  2  4  1  5  6  6  3  6  5  6  5  4  4  6  3  6  7  6  8
#>  [76]  6  7  6  5  5  8  6  5  0  4  2  9  9 12  4  5  0  7  3  6  4  3  8  3  4
```

This approach fails if $f(x;\theta)$ is long-tailed (e.g., `dnbinom(x - 2L, theta, 0.01)`).

Here is another approach that uses memoization to compute only as much of the CDF as needed, based on a uniform sample:

```
set.seed(921078628)
f <- function(x, theta) dnbinom(x - 2L, theta, 0.01) # example f(x;theta)
alpha <- 0.1; beta <- 0.04; theta <- 3.5 # example values
cdf <- c(alpha, alpha + beta)
dr <- function(n, theta, f) {
  U <- runif(n)
  maxU <- max(U)
  const <- 1 - cdf[2]
  i <- length(cdf)
  while(cdf[i] < maxU) {
    if (i == length(cdf)) length(cdf) <- i*2L
    cdf[i <- i + 1L] <- cdf[i] + const*f(i, theta)
  }
  findInterval(U, cdf <<- cdf[1:i], left.open = TRUE) # sample with memoization
}
dr(10L, theta, f) # generate 10 samples (notice the size of cdf changes)
#>  [1] 451   0 619 240 138 637 623 465 194 534
dr(100L, theta, f) # generate 100 samples (notice the size of cdf changes again)
#>   [1]  271  268    1  412  502  535  668  189    1    0  133    0  236  601  266
#>  [16]    0  114  184    1  471  217  414  244   41  226  101    0  144    0  426
#>  [31]  662  359  322  649  345  189  289    0  420  129  129  848    0    0  200
#>  [46]  314  730  273  554    0  193  161  406  115    0  171    0  226  278  167
#>  [61]  469  152  307  120  474  140  298  115    0  108  509  115    1  360  236
#>  [76]  734  624  647 1063  222    0  402  292  442  162  212  426  525  407  212
#>  [91]  334  266  437  424  321   72  238  123  235    0
```

Comment: I have run the first program and it seems to work greatly. my $f(x;\theta)$ is not long tailed but thanks for that too.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Xi'an:

Start by creating a table containing:

1. $k=0,1,2,...,n_\text{large}$
2. $p_k=P(X=k)$

Then sample from your PMF with the `sample` function with parameters:

- `x = k`
- `prob = p_k`
- `replace = TRUE`
- `size = N` (1000 in your example)